# Different graphql endpoint for authenticated requests

Tags: apollo-server

How do you provide a different endpoint for authenticated GraphQL queries using Apollo Server? i.e. /graphql for public queries and /auth/graphql for private queries? I can find plenty of examples for doing both over a single endpoint but none for multiple endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using apollo-server-express, you can create multiple ApolloServer instance and applyMiddleware to express app.

```
const app = express();
// create server1, server2 with its schema
// then
server1.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/auth/graphql' });
server2.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
```